# FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser always returns Null

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get user data from firebase and store it in MongoDB but FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser is always returning Null therefore all user data is also showing Null. This is the code.

```
class StoreUserData {
  Future<void> postData() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:3000/data');
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    final data = {
      'username': user?.displayName,
      'email': user?.email,
      'uid': user?.uid,
    };

    final jsonData = jsonEncode(data);

    final response = await http.post(url, body: jsonData, headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Post request successful');
      print(response.body);
    } else {
      print('Error: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Are you calling this method just after signin? Try adding authlistener to get the event when the user signs in and then call this method.